# Including Angular 5 application as iFrame in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

Having an application built on Angular 5 which is a file uploader sending data to database using Spring.
Now there is a Master Application built on AngularJS (Angular 1).

How can i include Angular 5 application as an iframe somewhere on any page in AngularJs application. I cannot upgrade master application to Angular 5 it will only be in AngulaJS (Angular 1).

To be specific again - "How to include Angular 5 application as an iFrame in AngularJS application".

I did not find answer for this anywhere..

Comment: Nothing special has to be done, just have an iframe and link to the application.  Done.  However... these application will not be able to communicate with each other, so keep that in mind.

Comment: thanks for help it worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an application to be pulled into iFrame, it doesn't matter how it is implemented, all you need is its URL.

```
<iframe src="link_to_your_angular_5_app"></iframe>
```

Use this piece of code anywhere in your angularJs apps template.